# how to bind dynamic list of composite components to panelGroup

Tags: jsf

composite component xhtml:

```
<composite:interface componentType="metroComponent">
        <composite:attribute name="uniqueId" />
    </composite:interface>


    <composite:implementation>

        <rich:panel width="100%" header="#{msgs['pages.metroEth.header2']}">
            <table class="resData">
                <tr>
                    <td class="labelLeft"><h:outputLabel id="optionLabelId"
                            value="#{msgs['pages.ccparams.serviceOption']}" /></td>
                    <td><h:inputText id="optionTextId"
                            binding="#{cc.serviceOption}" size="15" /> <h:message
                            for="ccvodTextId" style="color:red" /></td>

            </table>
        </rich:panel>

    </composite:implementation>

</ui:composition>
```

component type implementation is as follow:

```
@FacesComponent (value="metroComponent")
public class HtmlMetroCC extends UIComponentBase implements NamingContainer {

    UIInput serviceOption;

    public UIInput getServiceOption() {
        return serviceOption;
    }

    public void setServiceOption(UIInput serviceOption) {
        this.serviceOption = serviceOption;
    }

    @Override
    public String getFamily() {

        return "javax.faces.NamingContainer";
    }


}
```

there is also a backing bean which prepare panelGroup element with list of presented above composite components. i removed getters/setters for better reading

```
@ManagedBean (name="metroethernetBean")
@RequestScoped
public class MetroEthernetMBean implements IBean{

    private MetroEthCCData metroCCData;

    private HtmlPanelGroup metroCCPanel;
    private List<HtmlMetroCC> metroCClist;



    @PostConstruct
    public void initBean(){

        metroCClist = new ArrayList<HtmlMetroCC>();
        metroCCPanel = new HtmlPanelGroup();

        HtmlMetroCC initialMetroCC = new HtmlMetroCC(); 
        metroCClist.add(initialMetroCC);

        processMetroCCPanel();

    }


    private void processMetroCCPanel(){
        metroCCPanel.getChildren().clear();

        for (HtmlMetroCC comp: metroCClist){
            metroCCPanel.getChildren().add(comp);
        }   

    }   
}
```

page fragment responsible for displaying panelGroup looks like this:

```
<h:panelGroup id="metroCCPanelGrouId" binding="#{metroethernetBean.metroCCPanel}" />
```

the question is, why my composite components are not presented on panel? it looks panel has no children added at all..

when I put it as follows on page:

```
<gui:metroCC />
```

then composite comp. is displayed properly on page. What i want to achive is a panel on page with composite components which can be added or removed dynamically by clickin add new or delete selected

Answer (score 1):

There is a wrokaround, instead of binding dynamically created panel in menaged bean

```
<h:panelGroup id="metroCCPanelGrouId" binding="#{metroethernetBean.metroCCPanel}" />
```

use mBean to initialize list/add new/ remove and loop through it on page:

```
<h:panelGroup id="metroCCPanelGrouId">
    <ui:repeat var="test" value="#{metroethernetBean.metroCClist}">
        <gui:metroCC binding="#{test}" />
    </ui:repeat>
</h:panelGroup>
```

BUT: still don't understand why doing it with my first aproach fails...... BaluC, where are you ;)